# How to upload pandas, sqlalchemy package in lambda to avoid error "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'importlib_metadata'"?

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda

I'm trying to upload a deployment package to my AWS lambda function following the article https://korniichuk.medium.com/lambda-with-pandas-fd81aa2ff25e. My final zip file is as follows: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NLjvf_-Ks50E8z53DJezHtx7-ZRmwwBM/view but when I run my lambda function I get the error `Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'importlib_metadata'` 
[image: errorimg]

My handler is named `lambda_function.lambda_handler` which is the file name and the function to run. I also tried uploading these zip files as layers excluding the `lambda_function.py` and get:
[image: layerErr]
What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I tried using `zip/lambda_function.lambda_handler` as my handler still getting `Unable to import module 'zip/lambda_function': No module named 'zip/lambda_function'`

Comment: Why not use pre-existing pandas layer?

Comment: @Marcin How do I use pre-existing pandas layer? You mean clone some git repository? Or it is provided by aws lambda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [third party github repo](https://github.com/keithrozario/Klayers) with public layers, including pandas. You don't have to do anything to use, except adding the layer arn to your function. The arn [depends on your region](https://github.com/keithrozario/Klayers/tree/master/deployments/python3.8/arns), so you have to choose your region. For example, for `us-east-1` the pandas layer for python 3.8 is:

```
arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:770693421928:layer:Klayers-python38-pandas:31
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This solution saves a lot of time and really easy to implement.

Comment: @eras'q No problem. Glad it helped.